# How to Make a Control "move-able" on User-End in Silverlight 4

Tags: silverlight-4.0, c#-4.0, controls, draggable

I have a text block on my page.  Basically, I'd like to allow the user to be able to click and drag this text block to move it wherever they would like on the page.  From what I could tell there are no properties in the text block control that I can tinker with to allow the user to do this.

I didn't know if there was a property I was just overlooking.  I assume I have to go about this a different way, though, and so would this be best gone about through a series of click/mouse movement events, or is there an easier way to reach my end goal of making this control "move-able" by the user?

I am programming in Silverlight-4.0, C#-4.0, with the Visual Studio 2010 environment,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look on the following link:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc189066(VS.95).aspx

Silverlight Toolkit has also a dragdrop manager.

There is also the following project on CodePlex that may interest you:
http://silverlightdragdrop.codeplex.com/

Comment: The first link (to MSDN) is just what I needed, only took some minor tweaking to fit my variables and whatnot.  Thank you so much, and have a wonderful day!

Comment: @AmbiguousX: I am glad it was usefull. Have a great day you too.